# Test a Chart.js canvas with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, protractor, chart.js

I'm fairly new to protractor so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm looking into testing an application and need test the values inside a Chart.js graph.

Has anyone got any ideas on how to get  my protractor program to look inside the canvas.

This is the canvas output in HTML.

```
<canvas id="test" 
        class="chart chart-line ng-isolate-scope" 
        data="test.data" 
        labels="test.labels" 
        series="test.series" 
        legend="true" 
        options="test.options" 
        colours="test.colours" 
        width="1816" 
        height="800" 
        style="width: 908px; 
        height: 400px;">
</canvas>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor can get attributes of the canvas, but it can't access object created within it. But it depends what you're looking to do. Strategies for canvas testing might include [image diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852090/test-canvas-drawings-with-protractor), and [string diffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852090/test-canvas-drawings-with-protractor), and often [make use of `browser.actions`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1369) for manipulating them.

Comment: Hi I'd be looking to return the value of characters stored inside it.

Comment: Ahh... I misunderstood your question. No, you can't access elements within the canvas. I updated my answer for that. But the test strategies I listed might help you find a way to test around this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may get the underlying chart data, by [evaluating](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate) in the `canvas`'s context. Example:

```
var canvas = element(by.css("canvas#test[data]"));
canvas.evaluate("test.data").then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Granted it's years later, but today in typescript this code gives a compile-time error of Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. Thoughts?