# Protractor - Get array from canvas attribute in Angular2 using ng2-charts/Chart.js

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, chart.js

I'm using ng2-charts which is based on chart.js
Using it in my Angular 2 Application I want to check some data with my protractor test in one of the attributes of the `<canvas>` element.

I can't find a way to access the data. I found solutions with evaluate but I'm not sure if that's for Angular1 or 2.

Following solution with evaluate did not work for me:
[Test a Chart.js canvas with Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763255/test-a-chart-js-canvas-with-protractor/34769019)

My canvas setup:

```
  <div style="display: block">
    <canvas id="test" 
            [datasets]="chartData"
            [labels]="chartLabels"
            [options]="ChartOptions"
            [legend]="showRegions"
            [chartType]="barChartType" 
            height="100%"></canvas>
  </div>
```

When the page is loaded the canvas element looks like this (I removed the label attributes for convinience).

```
<canvas id="test" ng-reflect-datasets="[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-chart-type="bar" ng-reflect-legend="true"></canvas>
```

Now I find my canvas element like this:

```
var canvas = element(by.css("canvas#test[ng-reflect-datasets]"));
```

And from here I'm stuck. If I access the ng-reflect-datasets attribute I only get the string "[object Object]..." but I need the values inside these objects.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this...

```
var canvas = element(by.css("canvas#test[datasets]"));
canvas.evaluate("chartData").then(function (datasets) {
    // datasets is an array of objects that each have data, label, etc.
    console.dir(datasets[0].data);
});
```

Note, I just derived this from the SO answer in your question + my knowledge of ng2-charts (I have not used Protractor before).

Comment: I have tried all sorts of accessing the chartData.
And also with .evaluate("chartData). I didn't test the way you wrote the console output but the test doesn't even get to that point. I get an error already when evaluating saying: "angular is not defined".
To make sure the canvas is fully loaded I also testet browser.sleep bevore evluating anything. 
Didn't work either...